# Session not saved after Auth::attempt

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-10

I try to update my application from Laravwl 10 to Laravel 11. For the front end I use React + Inertia.

```
public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt([
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ], true)) return response()->json([
        'message' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
    ], 422);

    return response()->json([
        'message'   => 'Successfully login',
        'data'      => Auth::user(),
    ]);
}
```

This works just fine in Laravel 10. Auth::user() exists (success login), but the session not save my auth. For the session driver I use `database` and after I check my database, the user_id is null.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authentication), when you perform `Auth::attempt($credentials)` you should regenerate the user's session to prevent session fixation using the command `$request->session()->regenerate()`.

```
public function login(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $credentials = [
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        return response()->json([
            'message'   => 'Successfully login',
            'data'      => Auth::user(),
        ]);
    } else {
       return response()->json([
        'message' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
       ], 422);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I access the session through `$request`, it throws this message `Session store not set on request.`. If I regenerate directly from session helper `session()->regenerate();`, my auth is still not saved in the session. Middleware `StartSession` & `ShareErrorsFromSession` already included in the library.